# Just installed a new light near an existing one but one stays on, any help?

Tags: lighting, electrical-distribution

I installed a new light fixture near another using the power that comes from the switch (spliced into) and put a box in and took the power off that to my other light which was off that switch to begin with. What happens is I turn the power back on and one light is always on while the other is off, if I throw the switch it shuts other light off and turns other on.

Can someone tell me how to fix or give a diagram please. I have black white and ground. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the various boxes involved?

Comment: We're having trouble helping you without photos or at least diagrams of how things are wired, including the extant light.   It certainly does sound like a wiring problem of some kind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The switch seems to be acting as a three way that is jeff said is not wired properly,

1step:make sure it's not a three way switch and ther is indeeed only one switch in the house for those light, 
If this is the case and the only switch that turns on the existing lights, then you problem is most likely in how you wired them me personally, I would have just jacked the power directly from the the light and installed the new one as you did, the other

OBVIOUSLY DONT WORK LIVE especially diy, 
Anyway what I would is power down the switch and go back to the previous light fixture and see how they wired it

The three way switch is most likely the issue, I had the same one and it came down to me not wiring one then correctly 
What leads me to believe there is a three way involved is the fact one light stays one, switches don't work like that when a switch is off the brass connected in not in its terminal so it should not even function (not the old toggle switches or the new decoras) it's all the same function

Comment: Thanks guys for info, I fixed it by digging more and found the other light source had a terminal box and so I took power directly from that light to the other and the switch now turns them off and on, did not see there was this other box up there.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wire crossed. Typical series would be black to white from one light to the next, and white all the way through the series. 1st light: white wire from switch continues to the 2nd light, the black wire on the light is connected to the black wire from the switch. 2nd light: white wire from 1st light is connected to the black wire of the 2nd light and the white wire on the second light is connected to the white wire from the switch.

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
                                 W
BBBBB(light)WWWWWBBBBB(light)WWWWW
```

Comment: The only problem with that wiring is locating 60 **volt** bulbs that match.